# Displaying / Setting USB BlueTooth Buffer Size

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, serial-port

In Windows 7 there is a sequence of mouse clicks on various icons which will display the buffer size of a given Com Port.

I can't remember that sequence at this moment.

I know I did it once before. Anybody remember this trick ?

Comment: I like your style!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to say going to **Device Manager**, right-clicking a **COM Port** entry, clicking on **Properties**, selecting the **Port Settings** tab and clicking the **Advanced** button to see the following dialog?

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks for answering. The pic you pasted is all I've been able to find. I know perfectly well that I saw, on my own screen, a window which presented me with a display that showed that the receive buffer for Com31 was 4096 bytes. Maybe it was possible to edit it; I don't really remember. I know I saw that with my own eyes, but for the life of me I can't recall what I clicked to make it happen. Could it be something built into Visual Studio 2010 ? Is there some freeware utility that does this ? I am **SO** totally annoyed at myself for forgetting that mouse click sequence.